# printf behavior

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Take `int ptr={10,20,30,40,50}` 
I understand that

```
print("%d", *ptr++);
```

in such a statement evaluation of operators is from right to left.
Hence in `*ptr++`  the `++` will get evaluated first and then `ptr` and then `*`
So to confirm the same I wrote a program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int array[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int *q1 = array;
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1++);
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1);
}
```

The output of above program is different than the expected operator precedence by above logic.
The output  I got is

```
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e0
*q1++ = 10
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e4
*q1++ = 20
```

but I was expecting

```
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e0
*q1++ = 20
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e4
*q1++ = 20
```

so did the operator precedence not happened right to left?
Or there is some thing wrong in my understanding?

**UPDATE**

Now here is the thing.Even if I put these brackets as  mentioned so that *(ptr++) gets executed the output does not change here is new code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int array[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int *q1 = array;
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*(q1++));// note the braces here *(q1++) so that () get evaluated 
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1);
}
```

The result is still the same note the use of braces as you mentioned.
Still the output is

```
q1 = 0x7fff043f2120
*q1++ = 10 <-- I expected *q1++ = 20//since I used braces ()
q1 = 0x7fff043f2124
*q1++ = 20
```

So even after I used  braces *(ptr++) that operation ++ was still executed after the current line was executed.So did curly brace () not work? Or it was not given preferences over post increment thing?

Comment: The *result* of the expression `x++` is the value of `x` before the increment.  The *result* of `++x` is `x + 1`.  Both expressions have the same *side effect* of adding 1 to `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`++` on the right returns the value *before* it gets evaluated.

```
printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1++);
```

is the same as

```
printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1);
++q1;
```

Comment: as per some one's suggestion I used braces i.e. `printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*(q1++));` but still the behavior remained the same as you explained.
 What can be reason for these braces being not effecting in post increment condition?

Comment: @Registered User, unlike the other posters, I skipped over your operator precedence part on purpose, because it has absolutely no bearing what-so-ever to the problem you're having. That's just how `++` works. If you want a pre-increment, feel free to replace it with `*++q1`.

Answer (score 7):

No, operators don't get evaluated right to left. There is an [operator precedence table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx) that gives the order.

However, this is not the reason for the behavior you are seeing. The reason is that you are using the *post-increment* operator, which means that in `*q1++` the pointer dereference happens on the value that of `q1` had *before* the addition.

If you change the code to read `*(++q1)` (pre-increment operator) you would see the behavior you expect.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: [It prints 20 and 20 for me](http://www.ideone.com/sM6mi) just right. Are you sure you 've got everything correct?

Comment: I read your operator precedence table in that it is given
`++ post fix increment left to right` is that what you want to point.You mentioned `the pointer dereference happens on the value that of q1 had before the addition.` that is correct but that happened after the printf got executed.So my question is why did that icrement not happened in printf and printf showed the result after all ++ is supposed to increase the value of q1 in printf but that happened after printf got executed that thing is not clear.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: Operator precedence has nothing to do with what you are seeing; I only mentioned it to make this point clear. When you do `*q1++`, what happens is: 1) `*q1` is evaluated (to the integer value `10`), 2) The result 10 is passed to `printf`, 3) Finally, `q1` is incremented. If it's still not clear, I suggest studying some explanatory text on pre- and post- increment operators.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `*ptr++;` will evaluate the value that ptr points to first, and *then* increment ptr. To increment first, use `*++ptr;`.

Answer (score 1):

Having the `++` after the variable name is definitionally a post-increment operation meaning the pointer is advanced after the expression is evaluated.

x = *q++;

is the same as:

```
x = *q;
++q;
```

The pre-increment equivalent is:

```
x = *++q;
```

which would be:

```
++q;
x = *q;
```

Comment: that was a good answer I was looking for the same, in this case `printf("*p1 = %d \n",*q1++);` what is the expression ,I mean to say what do you consider as expression in this statement.

Comment: The expression would be the `*q1++` part. If it is something like `printf( "*p1 = %d and %d and %d\n", *q1++, *q1++, *q1++ );` I think it is officially ambiguous for the `printf` but on the following line `q1` will have been advanced 3-times.